# MySQL HAVING with calculated and regular field

Tags: mysql, having

I have a query which needs to select a calculated value based on several fields, but only if the result of the calculation is different from an existing field. So let's say it looks something like this:

```
SELECT ProductID
     , PastProfits
     , ((UnitPrice - UnitCost) * UnitsSold) AS CurrentProfits
  FROM product
 WHERE UnitsSold > 10
HAVING CurrentProfits <> PastProfits;
```

Now, the problem is that I don't actually need `PastProfits` in my result set. But if I leave `PastProfits` out of the `SELECT`, I can't access it in the `HAVING` clause. There are several workarounds I can think of:

1. Include `PastProfits` in the `SELECT`, as demonstrated above, and compare the fields in a `HAVING` clause. (Or I could put the whole thing in a subquery with a `WHERE` clause in the outer query, but there's probably no point in that.)
2. Add a `GROUP BY ProductID, PastProfits` so the field is visible in the `HAVING` clause.
3. Use a user-defined variable to store the result of the calculation in the `WHERE` clause. For example:

   ```
   SELECT ProductID
        , @profit AS CurrentProfits
     FROM product
    WHERE UnitsSold > 10
      AND (@profit:=((UnitPrice - UnitCost) * UnitsSold)) <> PastProfits;
   ```

Anyway, the point of my question is: What are the relative advantages and disadvantages of these methods? Are any of them more "correct"? Which one is likely to perform best? Is there some other approach I missed?

Comment: Excellent question. I'm not near a terminal to benchmark, but my inclination would be to use the user-defined variable. I'm eduguessing that it's performance is at least as good as the others and the syntax is crystal clear to me. If I had to do this query portably, I'd probably fallback onto #2. Since I'm sure you're going to get a great, definitive answer from someone like @BillKarwin, I'll leave this as but a mere opinionated comment.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to move the predicate to the `WHERE` clause; you would need to repeat the expression rather than referencing the alias assigned to the expression in the SELECT list, e.g.

```
SELECT ProductID
     , ((UnitPrice - UnitCost) * UnitsSold) AS CurrentProfits
  FROM product
 WHERE UnitsSold > 10
   AND ((UnitPrice - UnitCost) * UnitsSold) <> PastProfits
```

If your goal is to avoid repeating the expression, you could use an inline view (at the cost of a performance penalty). Use your current query as a rowsource (derived table) for an outer query:

```
SELECT v.ProductID
     , v.CurrentProfits
  FROM ( 
         SELECT ProductID
              , PastProfits
              , ((UnitPrice - UnitCost) * UnitsSold) AS CurrentProfits
           FROM product
          WHERE UnitsSold > 10
         HAVING CurrentProfits <> PastProfits
       ) v
```

The user-defined variable doesn't appear to offer a reliable solution; MySQL documentation warns against using a user-defined variable within a statement like this; the behavior may be unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

The "correct" way to write the query is to copy the expression in the `where` clause:

```
SELECT ProductID, ((UnitPrice - UnitCost) * UnitsSold) as CurrentProfits
FROM product
WHERE UnitsSold > 10 and ((UnitPrice - UnitCost) * UnitsSold) <> PastProfits;
```

This is standard SQL and it doesn't require using any MySQL-specific extensions (such as using `having` without `group by`).  If you weren't using MySQL, I would suggest:

```
SELECT ProductId, CurrentProfits
FROM (SELECT ProductID, ((UnitPrice - UnitCost) * UnitsSold) AS CurrentProfits
      FROM product
      WHERE UnitsSold > 10
    ) p
WHERE CurrentProfits <> PastProfits;
```

Alas, in MySQL, this is likely to be more expensive because the subquery is materialized.

Of your three choices, (1) and (2) are reasonable.

The third option makes assumptions about the processing of variables.  In general, MySQL does not guarantee the order of variable processing, so I would avoid that.